# Cannot ssh and ping into my CentOS VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, centos, virtualbox

I donwloaded the virtualbox image from this website:
https://www.osboxes.org/centos/#centos-782003-info
I uses CentOS 7.8.2003
I am able to start the VirtualBox but I cannot ssh into it. Then, I realized that I also cannot ping to the IP address. I already configure the network to Bridge.

[image: vm1]

[image: vm2]

Do I need to configure something on CentOS Virtual Box for me to be able to ssh into it from the Host machine? Thank you very much in advance.

[image: vm3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably post this on Superuser or Serverfault.

Anyway, I see you have 192.168.0.30 on your host machine, try configuring 192.168.0.31 on interface enp0s3 on your VM and restart the network.

You should be able to ping now.

Comment: Thank you very much @zorry When you said to configure the interface enp0s3, it means I have to configure this file right?
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
Please, see my new attachment, which line should I change to add the new IP address 192.168.0.31? Should I add a new line with IPADDR=192.168.0.31

Comment: I just noticed, just try ifup enp0s3 an see what IP you have, bootproto is set to dhcp so you should get the next available one. If you can ping it and don't need a static IP just change ONBOOT=yes.

Comment: Thank you @zorry I also posted on superuser forum. I tried the command "ifup enp0s3" but I get this error message
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (not available address, timeout, etc.)

Comment: thank you for your idea. I found out a way to add IPADDR to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3, then I changed BOOTPROTO to static and leaving ONBOOT=no
Now I can ssh into this VM. Thank you again!

Comment: @zorry You are right. This is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]